# When Dolphin lists the results of a search, how can you display the full path of a result?

Tags: search, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. When Dolphin lists the results of a search, how can I find the full path to one of the results?

Comment: Don't you have `Copy Location` in the right-click-menu?

Comment: Copy Location simply isn't in the menu that I get after right-clicking an item (eithr

Comment: Copy Location is not in the menu that I get after right-clicking either a file or a folder.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly would the (nonexistent) Copy Location action do anyway? I can get the effect of Move by dragging the files to the place I want them to be, but that is only reliable if the dragging distance is small.  If it's not small, it's too easy for the mouse to slip a bit and make the file(s) land in the wrong place.

Comment: It would be very nice if Shift-righticlick

Comment: I was starting to say that it would be very nice if shifting would change Copy into Move.

Answer (score 1):

In the search result, do a right-click on the result headers (e.g. Name, Size, etc.). In the submenu that pops up, you'll find "path" under "other" category.

This at least works for me on KDE Neon 5.24.

[image]